# Improper auto line-break in quoted latex expression

Tags: support, mathjax

I have this problem with Latex within quote.

For example, I want to show the following text in quote:

> Let $(I, \leq)$ be an ordered index
>   set, and let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathcal{F}_t, \mathbb{P})$ be a
>   filtered probability space.

If I type the following text in edit box:

```
Let $(I, \leq)$ be an ordered index set, and let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{F}_t, \mathbb{P})$ be a filtered probability space.
```

and then quote it, the system will automatically break line in the middle of a Latex expression,

```
> Let $(I, \leq)$ be an ordered index
> set, and let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},
> \mathcal{F}_t, \mathbb{P})$ be a
> filtered probability space.
```

resulting in  an additional ">" in the middle of the latex expression $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},> \mathcal{F}_t, \mathbb{P})$:

> Let $(I, \leq)$ be an ordered index
>   set, and let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},
>     > \mathcal{F}_t, \mathbb{P})$ be a
>   filtered probability space.

I was wondering if there is any solution? Thanks!

Comment: Use linebreaks, line good gentleman.

Comment: @Mariano: Thanks, but what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Why not just write the quotation character (">") yourself? You don't *have* to press the toolbar button. :-)

Comment: @Rabul: I hit Ctrl+Q.

Comment: Why not just write the quotation character (">") yourself? You don't *have* to hit Ctrl+Q. :-)

Comment: @RahulNarain: That is what I wrote in my answer! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the problem can be solved by putting a `>` before the first line of the quote. Not necessarily to put it in front of every line.

For example,

> Let $(I, \leq)$ be an ordered index
>    set, and let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},
>  \mathcal{F}_t, \mathbb{P})$ be a
>    filtered probability space.

Its code is

```
> Let $(I, \leq)$ be an ordered index
 set, and let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},
     \mathcal{F}_t, \mathbb{P})$ be a
 filtered probability space.
```

Answer (score 3):

The blockquote editor function isn't quite smart enough to understand MathJax `$` and `$$` syntax -- if you want to blockquote a section with, I suggest doing so manually, by making sure each line begins with `>`.